# Drop Table Hive

Tags: hive

I need to remove a few lines from a parquet table (table_a) in Hive. If I create a new table (Table_b), and insert into it:

```
Insert Overwrite table table_b 
select * from table_a
Where (my conditions to exclude the right fields here)
```

Are both tables now using the same HDFS file? If I drop table_a with purge, will both table's data disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `describe formatted <table name>` to check the hdfs path of the table.

To your question, if you've not specified any location while creating the table, the hdfs path of table a, and hdfs path of table b will be different
And if you drop table after loading the data to table b, you'll not lose data in table b